# Google Maps API V3 Overlay Interface

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'd like to setup a website using Google Maps API V3 using a custom overlay interface the way you can see it on this website (right hand side) http://predict.habhub.org/

I've searched Stackoverflow and the developers website of google, but couldn't find any helpful information.

Are there any samples, best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use absolutely positioned elements for this, with a z-index higher than 9 (which is the z-index of the gmaps map container).  For the dragging, you would then apply whatever jquery library you like to pull the elements around, as long as they are `position: absolute;`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dYUEa/)